# String interpolation with R's glue on a vector, without calling it multiple times

Tags: r, string-interpolation, r-glue

I'm looking to do string interpolation with R's `glue::glue()` on a vector, without calling it multiple times.

Example:

```r
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10)

glue::glue("No. of Rows: {dim(df)[1]}, No. of Columns: {dim(df)[2]}")
```

Would give as required:

> No. of Rows: 10, No. of Columns: 1

But I'm calling `dim(df)` twice, where it is a vector of length 2.

I was wondering if `glue` can handle this similar to string interpolation in Python with the % operator:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"x": range(10)})
print('No. of Rows: %d, No. of Columns: %d' % df.shape)
```

Which gives the same required output without calling `df.shape` twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do this:

```
glue("nr = {x[1]}, nc = {x[2]}", x = dim(mtcars))
# nr = 32, nc = 11
```

From the `?glue` documentation, the description of `...` is:

> Unnamed arguments are taken to be expressions string(s) to format. Multiple inputs are concatenated together before formatting. **Named arguments are taken to be temporary variables available for substitution.**

(Emphasis mine, highlighting the part relevant to this question.)

Answer (score 3):

You could use this, similar to Python's f-string interpolation:

```r
shape <- dim(df)
glue::glue("No. of Rows: {shape[1]}, No. of Columns: {shape[2]}")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can do it natively, but one thing you could do would be to wrap it in a function:

```r
f <- function(x) glue::glue("No. of Rows: {x[1]}, No. of Columns: {x[2]}")

f(dim(df))
```